# Why doesn't QGIS automatically find the new plugin update during startup?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I have done a plugin for QGIS and I made a repository (xml) for the end users to install it. Then, I made a new version and update also my repository file with the new one but Qgis doesn't automaticaly find the new update during startup. Where should I flag the new version? I flag the new version in xml file like that:from `<version>1.0.0</version> changed to <version>1.0.1</version>` but Qgis doesn't recognize any new version.

Comment: Make sure you have changed the version also in metadata.txt and __init__.py files and init.

Answer (score 1):

I found it!
I haven't update the version attribute in ***pyqgis_plugin*** tag:

`<pyqgis_plugin name="my plugin" version="1.0.1" plugin_id="148">`